# An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-4, passenger

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Setup rails on amazon ec2 with rubber, with passenger 4.0.23.
2. Deploy
3. Check apache logs

**What is the expected output? What do I see instead?**

I expect a working rails website. I get page cannot be displayed.

**Version of Phusion Passenger,rails, OS**

Rails 4.0.0
Passenger 4.0.23
OS Ubuntu 12.04 on Amazon EC2

**Additional information below.**

I used rubber gem to setup amazon ec2 instance. Everything worked great. And deployment was successful. But I couldnt see my app live. I checked teh apache logs and there are passenger errors there.

```
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9413 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-12 16:39:57 -0500
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9487 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout] Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as */*
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9489 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9490 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered pages/home.html.slim within layouts/application (1.4ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9491 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.slim (1.0ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9492 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_mob_os_icons.html.slim (0.0ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9493 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_social_icons.html.slim (0.0ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9494 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.slim (0.5ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9520 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_support_form.html.slim (3.8ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:57.9524 31599/7f14572a4700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 31913 stdout] Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 8.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:39:58.0194 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 2343 stdout] 
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:06.8283 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:305 ]: Preloader for /mnt/aniways_website-production/releases/20131112204117 started on PID 2343, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31592/generation-0/backends/preloader.2343
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1492 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:693 ]: An error occurred while spawning a process: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1494 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:694 ]: The application preloader seems to have crashed, restarting it and trying again...
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1727 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr] /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:66:in `fork': Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1729 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:66:in `accept_and_process_next_client'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1730 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:116:in `run_main_loop'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1810 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:151:in `<module:App>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1811 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:07.1812 31599/7f145e882700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2343 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:08.7635 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 2491 stdout] 
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.0087 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:305 ]: Preloader for /mnt/aniways_website-production/releases/20131112204117 started on PID 2491, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.31592/generation-0/backends/preloader.2491
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1094 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr] /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:66:in `fork'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1111 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr] : Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1113 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:66:in `accept_and_process_next_client'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1114 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/lib/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb:116:in `run_main_loop'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1115 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:151:in `<module:App>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1117 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.1118 31599/7f145e78a700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 2491 stderr]    from /usr/local/rubies/2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/passenger-4.0.23/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
[website]       [ 2013-11-12 16:40:13.2386 31599/7f145e841700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:849 ]: Could not spawn process for group /mnt/aniways_website-production/releases/20131112204117#default: An error occurred while starting the web application. It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
[website]            in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::throwAppSpawnException(const string&, Passenger::SpawnException::ErrorKind, Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Spawner::NegotiationDetails&)' (Spawner.h:689)
[website]            in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::SpawnResult Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::sendSpawnCommand(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:682)
[website]            in 'Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::SpawnResult Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::sendSpawnCommandAgain(const Exception&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&) [with Exception = Passenger::SpawnException]' (SmartSpawner.h:692)
[website]            in 'virtual Passenger::ApplicationPool2::ProcessPtr Passenger::ApplicationPool2::SmartSpawner::spawn(const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&)' (SmartSpawner.h:760)
[website]            in 'void Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Group::spawnThreadRealMain(const SpawnerPtr&, const Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Options&, unsigned int)' (Implementation.cpp:782)
[website]
```

**UPDATE**

Following Hongli's advice, I reduced MaxPoolSize to 5.

Now, I get this in error log.

```
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:07.5599 5103/7fa04475e740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:619 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5096/generation-0/request
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:07.5780 5108/7f4e3dddd740 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:318 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5096/generation-0/logging
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:07.5820 5100/7f470d55d740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:761 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Wed Nov 13 14:12:07 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) proxy_html/3.0.1 mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/1.0.1 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.23 configured -- resuming normal operations
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:11.0335 5103/7fa044687700 Pool2/Spawner.h:796 ]: [App 5252 stdout] 
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.0589 5103/7fa044687700 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:305 ]: Preloader for /mnt/jashwant_website-production/releases/20131113190730 started on PID 5252, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.5096/generation-0/backends/preloader.5252
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.3681 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout] Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-13 14:12:14 -0500
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.4019 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout] Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as */*
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.4101 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.5424 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered pages/home.html.slim within layouts/application (59.9ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.5987 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_header.html.slim (23.9ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.7445 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_mob_os_icons.html.slim (7.4ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.7631 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_social_icons.html.slim (7.2ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.7633 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.slim (155.8ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.8396 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout]   Rendered layouts/_support_form.html.slim (71.4ms)
[ 2013-11-13 14:12:14.8413 5103/7fa0445d0700 Pool2/Implementation.cpp:1274 ]: [App 5277 stdout] Completed 200 OK in 431ms (Views: 377.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I think this signifies successful server setup. But still I am not able to browse my site online. 
( I already have checked security groups, they allow 0.0.0.0 to port 80/443. Same goes with mysql. Rails `/log/production.log` is empty.

**UPDATE 2**
I see this in haproxy log

```
Nov 13 15:02:23 localhost haproxy[5580]: Server passenger_proxy/website is DOWN, reason: Layer7 wrong status, code: 404, info: "Not Found", check duration: 5ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 0 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Phusion Passenger author here.

Notice this in the logs?

```
 Cannot allocate memory - fork(2) (Errno::ENOMEM)
```

It means that your system has **run out of memory**.

And notice this?

```
 An error occurred while starting the web application.
 It exited before signalling successful startup back to Phusion Passenger.
```

It means that Passenger tried to spawn a process for your web app, but that failed, because of the aforementioned error (running out of memory).

There are 3 things you can do:

- Upgrade your memory.
- Upgrade your swap space.
- Tweak your Passenger settings so that it doesn't start as many processes. This saves you memory. Take a look at the Passenger manual for tweaking options.

Comment: I am actually on micro EC2 instance. How can I tweak passenger settings to work in my limited memory ?

Comment: Most important one is http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerMaxPoolSize

Comment: I destroyed the instance in the morning after giving up with passenger and started a nginx / unicorn instance. But when you (passenger author) came forward to help, I got some hope and I am again creating a server with passenger. I'll let you know if I find problems even after reducing MaxPoolSize.

Comment: No problem. Note that this is purely a configuration problem, not a Passenger problem. Since an EC 2 Micro instance has so little memory (600 MB) you should set the max pool size to 1 (the default is 6!). That will use the least amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks to you, I don't see an error now. But still unable to browse my site online. Updated my question to reflect the latest logs.

Comment: I'm not sure why HAProxy thinks your site is down. According to Passenger and the Nginx logs, your site is working fine. There are no errors. This is probably a HAProxy configuration problem (possibly related to timeouts) but unfortunately I can't help you with that.

Comment: Yes, passenger and nginx were fine. It was some firewall issues in amazon that wasnt allowing haproxy to work.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use Passenger+Nginx Modul. Below are the steps to install Ruby,rails and configure passenger.

1. INSTALL THE NEEDED LIBRARIES

   ```
   sudo apt-get install zlib1g zlib1g-dev build-essential openssl libssl-dev libmysqlclient18 libmysqlclient-dev libyaml-dev curl git-core python-software-properties libpq-dev nodejs
   ```
2. DOWNLOAD AND INSTALL RUBY 1.9.3

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.3
   ```

   OR

   ```
   wget ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.0/ruby-2.0.0-p195.tar.gz
   apt-get install wget build-eruby+rails+mysql+passenger+ngnixssential make     
   cd ruby-2.0.0
   $  ./configure
   $   make
   $   sudo make install
   ```

3.DOWNLOAD RUBY GEM: THE STANDARD RUBY PACKAGE MANAGER
not need to install, it's got install at time of ruby installation

4.INSTALL RAILS

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
sudo gem install rails
```

8.PASSENGER INSTALL

```
gem install passenger
```

9.INSTALL NGINX

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev or libcurl4-gnutls-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

10.START NGINX

```
    sudo service nginx start
```

Comment: Nginx has got nothing to do with it, and won't solve this problem. But if you're recommending the Nginx version anyway, you should recommend using the Phusion APT repository to install it, not the RubyGems version. The former prevents having to compile stuff.